# Is there a way to have a JSF inputText autocomplete from a database entity?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jpa, jsf-2, ejb-3.0

I have a (potentially huge) table say `crew`. I could store its entries in a view scoped bean but this sounds like a memory killer. I would like the user to be able though to have an `h:inputText` element when typing into which a name (say after she typed 3 characters) the database is queried and returns names of crew that match the characters typed. Ideally this would query the db only once (on typing the 3rd character) and then filter the list the query returned (on typing more chars).

Does this make sense ? Is there some other element that achieves this ?

Comment: PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable>` has features which makes this easy. So .. there's definitely a way. The question is: do you want to reinvent the wheel or use a component library which already did it for you?

Comment: @BalusC: If you could wipe some skeleton code I'd be grateful. I had sworn vanilla but I am tempted to add some syrup :)

Comment: FYI: Link is broken:. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml